# Windows azure project webrole and workrole

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I am learning windows azure on http://www.cnblogs.com/txsoft/p/4191323.html

I follow his steps and finally press F5 met a messagebox:

```
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException” (类型的未经处理的异常在 | type
> of unhandled exception) Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll (中发生
> 其他信息 | additional information): A duplicate property
> 'SharedAccessKeyName' was found in the Service Bus connection string.
```

and on output board:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException” (类型的第一次机会异常在 | First chance exception of type in) Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll (中发生 | occurred).
```

how do I to solve this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you translate all error messages into English.

Comment: According to the error message you have a problem in your service bus connection string. You can check it out in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file in the "DemoCloudService". Seems like a copy-paste problem ("duplicate property 'SharedAccessKeyName'")